# reading clipboard contents into array in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
  Range("C" & CStr(j) & ":C" & CStr(k)).Select
  Range("C" & CStr(j) & ":C" & CStr(k)).Copy
```

I am reading the contents of a column into the clipboard and I want to loop through every element.

The question is how do I loop through it?

The contents of the clipboard look like this:

```
1234
21345234
1234512345
123452135
123451235
2345
```

alternatively I should probably be looping through J and K? Can you please show me how to do this thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the clipboard for this, instead:

```
Dim workingArray as Variant

workingArray = Range ("C" & CStr(j) & ":C" & CStr(k))
```

Now you can work through workingArray, note that it's treated as a two-D array.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the range without the need for any weird syntax like this:

```
Dim cel as Range
For Each cel in Range(Cells(j,3), Cells(k,3))
    MsgBox cel.Value
Next cel
```

Note that the '3' in this case means the range is in the *third* column (which is 'C')